# Will a tvOS universal framework not include a i386 slice?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, xcode7, tvos

I am currently working on creating a tvOS universal framework, and I noticed that the simulator build doesn't include a i386 slice. After trying to fix this for some hours I remembered that the Apple TV is a 64-bit-only device. So... Does this means that there isn't a non-64 emulator and that the simulator builds won't ever include a i386 slice (No matter how hard I try)?

Comment: Is there any reason you need an i386 slice?

Comment: @AndreM No, if there's no i386 simulator. I just wan't to confirm that actually there's no i386 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your mac is also 64 bit so you should see a x86_64 slice when building for the simulator. Not sure how the tvOS frameworks are compiled, but if you really want to create an 386 slice, you could try to follow (some of )my directions outlined in this post (it still works mostly the same for xcode 7):

[Universal custom iOS framework using Xcode 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325668/universal-custom-ios-framework-using-xcode-6-4/32465314#32465314)

Comment: I am already doing something similar for building it (with a bash script), that's why I was surprised of no seeing the i386 slice there... That's why I am asking if this is normal.

Comment: It's not the best solution; you should be scripting it and using `xcodebuild`.  That way you can generate a build very simply, rather than messing around with complex commands (like `lipo`), which you will have to document anyway.  Therefore you may as well document it in the form of a script!

Comment: We are using a modified version of the script described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4 for this. The best way is to make a new build phase with it.